# How the following python string are generated?

Tags: python, string

I am reading this  [wsgi document](http://wsgi.tutorial.codepoint.net/parsing-the-request-get), I can not understand how the response_body is generated.

```
    {
        response_body = html % { # Fill the above html template in
        'checked-software': ('', 'checked')['software' in hobbies],
        'checked-tunning': ('', 'checked')['tunning' in hobbies],
        'age': age or 'Empty',
        'hobbies': ', '.join(hobbies or ['No Hobbies?'])
    }
```

Can anyone explain the python syntax?

```
'checked-software': ('', 'checked')['software' in hobbies],
```

Comment: Which part don't you understand? As it is there are multiple questions being asked as this syntax can be broken down into numerous parts.

Answer (score 3):

Break it down:

```
{
    'checked-software': ('', 'checked')['software' in hobbies]
}
```

```
* 'checked-software': (...) 
    - assign the key 'checked-software' to the thing on the right-hand side
* ('', 'checked') 
    - a 2-tuple with '' and 'checked' as elements
* 'software' in hobbies' 
    - a True/False check if the string 'software' is in the hobbies variable
* ['software' in hobbies] 
    - a sequence-accessor based on the True/False check
```

Taking all that

```
'checked-software': ('', 'checked')['software' in hobbies]
```

Would mean:

- check if the string `'software'` is in the `hobbies` variable, this becomes `True` or `False`

  - If `False`, access the 0th element of `('', 'checked')`
  - If `True`, access the 1st element of `('', 'checked')`
- Assign that element to the `'checked-software'` key

This is using the fact that `True/False` are respectively `1` and `0` in Python, [because bools are integral types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-10).

> Booleans (bool)
>
> These represent the truth values False and True. The two objects representing the values False and True are the only Boolean objects. The Boolean type is a subtype of the integer type, and Boolean values behave like the values 0 and 1, respectively, in almost all contexts, the exception being that when converted to a string, the strings "False" or "True" are returned, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The slice at the end is a boolean, which is being used to reference the elements of the tuple.  This example might help;

```
dictionary = {'key': ('if false', 'if true')[True]}
print(dictionary)
```

`'software' in hobbies` will return either True(1) or False(0) for example.